# Responsive Navigation Bar (Mobile device issue)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been working on trying to make my navigation bar responsive, I have been using W3Schools as a guide to try and achieve a responsive navbar but was unable to succeed, I would like an icon to appear which will show when visiting my portfolio on a mobile device but I am unable to complete this task, below I will link the w3schools page I used, my code and an example of what it looks like on my website.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp

[Example of how it look on a phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE3dS.png)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mynav-area");
  if (x.className === "nav-area") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "nav-area";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: impact;
  margin: 0;
  background: #0F2027;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.fix {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav-area {
  z-index: 1;
  float: right;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  top: 1%;
}

.menu-area {
  float: right;
  top: 15%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px;
}

.menu-area li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
}

.menu-area li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menu-area li.active a {
  color: #FF00BD;
}

.menu-area li a:hover {
  color: #FF00BD;
}

.banner-text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.banner-text h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 80px;
  margin: 0;
}

.banner-text h3 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}

.banner-text-hi {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 80px;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.banner-text-hi h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 80px;
  margin: 0;
}

.banner-text-hi h3 {
  color: #FF00BD;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}

.banner-text-name {
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 3.5%;
  right: 55%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.banner-text-name h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.banner-text h2 span {
  color: #FF00BD;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
}

.snow {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.split {
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.33%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background: #0F2027;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}

.left h2 {
  color: aliceblue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.right h2 {
  color: aliceblue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.center {
  left: 33%;
  right: 33%;
  background: #0F2027;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background: #0F2027;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.centered img {
  width: 150px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.class1,
.class2,
.class3 {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

p {
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

@import "bourbon";
$col-primary: #00c7ec;
$corner-radius: 5px;
.button {
  z-index: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: $col-primary;
  border: 1px solid $col-primary;
  border-radius: $corner-radius;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding-left: 5em;
  padding-right: 5em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
  @include transition(all 0.2s ease-in);
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 transparentize($col-primary, 0.5);
    background-color: $col-primary;
    @include transition(all 0.2s ease-out);
    &:before {
      @include animation(shine 0.5s 0s linear);
    }
  }
  &:active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
    @include transition(box-shadow 0.2s ease-in);
  }
  &:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 86%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7%;
    left: 0%;
    opacity: 0;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px white;
    @include transform(skewX(-20deg));
  }
}

@include keyframes(shine) {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@import "compass/css3";
$width : 220px;
$height: 70px;
$border: 4px;
$violet: #6559ae;
$orange: #ff7159;
$deg : 120deg;
$size: 400%;
$dur : 3s;
@mixin clip-frame($width, $height, $border) {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, $border 100%, $border $border, $width - $border $border, $width - $border $height - $border, $border $height - $border, $border 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
}

.position {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

#workarea {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #1e1a3e;
  font-family: Raleway;
}

#personal {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 2%;
}


/*    start code for the actual button:         */


/*   
        Spot is the span on the inside of the href that
        fills the parent and makes the hover and link work
        for the entire div
    */

.spot {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


/*
        This is the outer svg wrapper that the SVG itself will 
        fill. Multiple svg-wrapper classes can be put side by side.
    */

.svg-wrapper {
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  /*make sure to use same height/width as in the html*/
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px
}


/*
      This is where we define the fill, color, thickness,
      and stroke pattern of the SVG when there is no hover.
      The dasharray and offset together define the line position
      under the words. Here's also where the transition speed is set.
    */

#shape {
  stroke-width: 6px;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #FF00BD;
  stroke-dasharray: 85 400;
  stroke-dashoffset: -220;
  transition: 1s all ease;
}


/* 
        Pushing the text up into the SVG. Without this the
        text would be below the div's.
    */

#text {
  margin-top: -35px;
  text-align: center;
}

#text a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}


/* 
        Changing the shape on hover. I change the color of the stroke,
    make it thinner, then set it to again wrap around the entire parent element.
    */

.svg-wrapper:hover #shape {
  stroke-dasharray: 50 0;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke: #FF00BD;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav-area a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}


/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav-area.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav-area.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .nav-area.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.nav-area .icon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Joe's Portfolio</title>
</head>


<body>
  <!-- Navigation Bar -->
  <header class="fix">
    <div class="nav-area">
      <ul class="menu-area">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="work.html">Coursework</a></li>
        <li><a href="future.html">Future Aspirations</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="cvpage.html.html">CV</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
      </ul>
      <!-- Navigation Bar End -->


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8ErC.png
```

Comment: I think you should add your "main.css" for better understanding.

Comment: Added @MohitGupta

Comment: Ok check now my Ans :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had un-ordered list whereas the tutorial has anchor tags inside a `<div>`. Check following updated code snippet. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**
Added `z-index: 5; position: sticky;` to the class `fix`, in order to bring header above rest of the content having `position:fixed;` in "About me" page.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: impact;
  margin: 0;
  background: #0F2027;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.fix {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 5;
  position: sticky;
}

header {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav-area {
  z-index: 1;
  float: right;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  top: 1%;
}

.menu-area {
  float: right;
  top: 15%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px;
}

.menu-area li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
}

.menu-area li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menu-area li.active a {
  color: #FF00BD;
}

.menu-area li a:hover {
  color: #FF00BD;
}

.banner-text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.banner-text h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 80px;
  margin: 0;
}

.banner-text h3 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}

.banner-text-hi {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 80px;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.banner-text-hi h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 80px;
  margin: 0;
}

.banner-text-hi h3 {
  color: #FF00BD;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}

.banner-text-name {
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 3.5%;
  right: 55%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.banner-text-name h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.banner-text h2 span {
  color: #FF00BD;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
}

.snow {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.split {
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.33%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background: #0F2027;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}

.left h2 {
  color: aliceblue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.right h2 {
  color: aliceblue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.center {
  left: 33%;
  right: 33%;
  background: #0F2027;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background: #0F2027;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.centered img {
  width: 150px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.class1,
.class2,
.class3 {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

p {
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

@import "bourbon";
$col-primary: #00c7ec;
$corner-radius: 5px;
.button {
  z-index: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: $col-primary;
  border: 1px solid $col-primary;
  border-radius: $corner-radius;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding-left: 5em;
  padding-right: 5em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
  @include transition(all 0.2s ease-in);
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 transparentize($col-primary, 0.5);
    background-color: $col-primary;
    @include transition(all 0.2s ease-out);
    &:before {
      @include animation(shine 0.5s 0s linear);
    }
  }
  &:active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
    @include transition(box-shadow 0.2s ease-in);
  }
  &:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 86%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7%;
    left: 0%;
    opacity: 0;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px white;
    @include transform(skewX(-20deg));
  }
}

@include keyframes(shine) {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@import "compass/css3";
$width: 220px;
$height: 70px;
$border: 4px;
$violet: #6559ae;
$orange: #ff7159;
$deg: 120deg;
$size: 400%;
$dur: 3s;
@mixin clip-frame($width, $height, $border) {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, $border 100%, $border $border, $width - $border $border, $width - $border $height - $border, $border $height - $border, $border 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
}

.position {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

#workarea {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #1e1a3e;
  font-family: Raleway;
}

#personal {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 2%;
}


/*    start code for the actual button:         */


/*   
        Spot is the span on the inside of the href that
        fills the parent and makes the hover and link work
        for the entire div
    */

.spot {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


/*
        This is the outer svg wrapper that the SVG itself will 
        fill. Multiple svg-wrapper classes can be put side by side.
    */

.svg-wrapper {
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  /*make sure to use same height/width as in the html*/
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px
}


/*
      This is where we define the fill, color, thickness,
      and stroke pattern of the SVG when there is no hover.
      The dasharray and offset together define the line position
      under the words. Here's also where the transition speed is set.
    */

#shape {
  stroke-width: 6px;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #FF00BD;
  stroke-dasharray: 85 400;
  stroke-dashoffset: -220;
  transition: 1s all ease;
}


/* 
        Pushing the text up into the SVG. Without this the
        text would be below the div's.
    */

#text {
  margin-top: -35px;
  text-align: center;
}

#text a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}


/* 
        Changing the shape on hover. I change the color of the stroke,
    make it thinner, then set it to again wrap around the entire parent element.
    */

.svg-wrapper:hover #shape {
  stroke-dasharray: 50 0;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke: #FF00BD;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav-area a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}


/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Joe's Portfolio</title>
</head>


<body>
  <!-- Navigation Bar -->
  <header class="fix">
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="work.html">Coursework</a>
      <a href="future.html">Future Aspirations</a>
      <a href="about.html">About Me</a>
      <a href="cvpage.html.html">CV</a>
      <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    </div>

  </header>
```

Comment: This works perfectly on my hompage but when I try to add it to my about me page, the navbar does not even appear. https://gyazo.com/63cb46773f9da89dd80dd441ccaa36c4

HTML for about me page: https://pastebin.com/Wssd2FCb
Full CSS: https://pastebin.com/esNa2bt7

Comment: I believe you have separate pages for all the menu links in header. So in that case you will need to add the `Header` section in all html pages.

Comment: I already have a header section in all my html pages which contains the navbar

Comment: OK. Can you share the code of _About me_ page? Have you added the `<header>` section from the answer snippet?

Comment: EDIT: It has something to do with the sections on my other pages which contain the icons and the button. The pages which do not contain these, the navbar works fine.

Comment: Yes, it was related to the positioning the section with Fixed positioning. Check updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! Only other issue is that when in mobile view, the dropdown of the nav doesnt show on the contact page and my buttons have stopped working. HTML for contact page (contains css). https://pastebin.com/8jbak9Na

Comment: I can neither see the definition for function `myFunction()` in html nor any local js file included. You will need to add in under script tag.

Comment: Any idea how to fix the buttons? They are no longer working after the .fix z-index was set to 5

Comment: Here is the codepen for contact form (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LqppNR). I'm little lost here on the button that you are talking about. Can you check and let me know which button are you talking about? (I'll be traveling now with little internet access, I'll try to reach back asap.)

Comment: The buttons under each of the images that reads "learn more" on my coursework, about us and future aspirations page, it used to have an animation and you used to be able to click it but now are unable to do so after the z-index for the "fix" class was changed to 5

Answer (score 1):

I have Updated responsive menu with your css and your html, check that, I hope this will help you.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mynav-area");
    if (x.className === "menu-area") {
      x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      x.className = "menu-area";
    }
  }
```

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: impact;
        margin: 0; 
        background: #0F2027; 
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }

    .fix {
        clear: both;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    header {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .nav-area {
        z-index: 1;
        float: right;
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }

.menu-area {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

    .menu-area li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .menu-area li a, .nav-area a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .menu-area li.active a{
        color: #FF00BD;
    }

    .menu-area li a:hover {
        color: #FF00BD;
    }

    .banner-text {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    .banner-text h2 {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 80px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .banner-text h3 {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin: 0;
    }   

    .banner-text-hi {
        position: absolute;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 80px;
        width: 60%;
        text-align: center;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .banner-text-hi h2 {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 80px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .banner-text-hi h3 {
        color: #FF00BD;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .banner-text-name {
        z-index: 1;
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
        color: #fff;
        width: 60%;
        text-align: center;
        top: 3.5%;
        right: 55%;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .banner-text-name h2 {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .banner-text h2 span {
        color: #FF00BD;
    }

canvas { 
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vh;
}
.snow { 
    pointer-events: none;
    position:fixed; 
    left: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.split {
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.33%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.left { 
  left: 0;
  background: #0F2027; 
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}

.left h2 {
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.right h2 {
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.center {
  left:33%;
  right:33%;
  background: #0F2027; 
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background: #0F2027; 
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.centered img {
  width: 150px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.class1,
.class2,
.class3 {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

p {
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}


@import "bourbon";

$col-primary: #00c7ec;
$corner-radius: 5px;

.button {
    z-index: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 30px;

  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: $col-primary;
  border: 1px solid $col-primary;
  border-radius: $corner-radius;

  line-height: 3em;
  padding-left: 5em;
  padding-right: 5em;

  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;

  @include transition(all 0.2s ease-in);

  &:hover {
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 transparentize($col-primary, 0.5);
    background-color: $col-primary;

    @include transition(all 0.2s ease-out);

    &:before {
      @include animation(shine 0.5s 0s linear);
    }
  }

  &:active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
    @include transition(box-shadow 0.2s ease-in);
  }

  &:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 86%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7%;
    left: 0%;

    opacity: 0;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px white;
    @include transform(skewX(-20deg));
  }
}

@include keyframes(shine) {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0%;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@import "compass/css3";

$width:  220px;
$height: 70px;
$border: 4px;

$violet: #6559ae;
$orange: #ff7159;

$deg:  120deg;
$size: 400%;
$dur:  3s;

@mixin clip-frame($width, $height, $border) {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, $border 100%, $border $border, $width - $border $border, $width - $border $height - $border, $border $height - $border, $border 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
}


.position {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

#workarea {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #1e1a3e;
  font-family: Raleway;
}

#personal {
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:15px;
  right:2%;
}
/*    start code for the actual button:         */


/*   
    Spot is the span on the inside of the href that
    fills the parent and makes the hover and link work
    for the entire div
*/

.spot {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
/*
    This is the outer svg wrapper that the SVG itself will 
    fill. Multiple svg-wrapper classes can be put side by side.
*/

.svg-wrapper {
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  /*make sure to use same height/width as in the html*/
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px
}
/*
  This is where we define the fill, color, thickness,
  and stroke pattern of the SVG when there is no hover.
  The dasharray and offset together define the line position
  under the words. Here's also where the transition speed is set.
*/

#shape {
  stroke-width: 6px;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #FF00BD;
  stroke-dasharray: 85 400;
  stroke-dashoffset: -220;
  transition: 1s all ease;
}
/* 
    Pushing the text up into the SVG. Without this the
    text would be below the div's.
*/

#text {
  margin-top: -35px;
  text-align: center;
}

#text a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
/* 
    Changing the shape on hover. I change the color of the stroke,
make it thinner, then set it to again wrap around the entire parent element.
*/

.svg-wrapper:hover #shape {
  stroke-dasharray: 50 0;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke: #FF00BD;
}
.nav-area .icon {
        display: none;
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
        .nav-area ul li:not(:first-child) {
          display: none;
          background: #212020;
          }
          ul.menu-area.responsive li:first-child {
          background: #212020;
          }
        .nav-area a.icon {
          float: right;
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          right: 0;
          top: 0;
        }
        .nav-area.responsive {position: relative;}

        ul.menu-area.responsive li {
          display: block;
          background: #3c3a3a;
        }
      }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Navigation Bar -->
<header class="fix">
  <div class="nav-area">
      <ul class="menu-area" id="mynav-area">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="work.html">Coursework</a></li>
          <li><a href="future.html">Future Aspirations</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
          <li><a href="cvpage.html.html">CV</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </a>
      </ul>
        </div>
      </header>

<!-- Navigation Bar End -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mynav-area");
  if (x.className === "nav-area") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "nav-area";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: impact;
  margin: 0;
  background: #0F2027;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.fix {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav-area {
  z-index: 1;
  float: right;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  top: 1%;
}

.menu-area {
  float: right;
  top: 15%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px;
}

.menu-area li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
}

.menu-area li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menu-area li.active a {
  color: #FF00BD;
}

.menu-area li a:hover {
  color: #FF00BD;
}

.banner-text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.banner-text h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 80px;
  margin: 0;
}

.banner-text h3 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}

.banner-text-hi {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 80px;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.banner-text-hi h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 80px;
  margin: 0;
}

.banner-text-hi h3 {
  color: #FF00BD;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}

.banner-text-name {
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 3.5%;
  right: 55%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.banner-text-name h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.banner-text h2 span {
  color: #FF00BD;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
}

.snow {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.split {
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.33%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background: #0F2027;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}

.left h2 {
  color: aliceblue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.right h2 {
  color: aliceblue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.center {
  left: 33%;
  right: 33%;
  background: #0F2027;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background: #0F2027;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.centered img {
  width: 150px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.class1,
.class2,
.class3 {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

p {
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

@import "bourbon";
$col-primary: #00c7ec;
$corner-radius: 5px;
.button {
  z-index: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: $col-primary;
  border: 1px solid $col-primary;
  border-radius: $corner-radius;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding-left: 5em;
  padding-right: 5em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
  @include transition(all 0.2s ease-in);
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 transparentize($col-primary, 0.5);
    background-color: $col-primary;
    @include transition(all 0.2s ease-out);
    &:before {
      @include animation(shine 0.5s 0s linear);
    }
  }
  &:active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
    @include transition(box-shadow 0.2s ease-in);
  }
  &:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 86%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7%;
    left: 0%;
    opacity: 0;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px white;
    @include transform(skewX(-20deg));
  }
}

@include keyframes(shine) {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@import "compass/css3";
$width : 220px;
$height: 70px;
$border: 4px;
$violet: #6559ae;
$orange: #ff7159;
$deg : 120deg;
$size: 400%;
$dur : 3s;
@mixin clip-frame($width, $height, $border) {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, $border 100%, $border $border, $width - $border $border, $width - $border $height - $border, $border $height - $border, $border 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
}

.position {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

#workarea {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #1e1a3e;
  font-family: Raleway;
}

#personal {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 2%;
}


/*    start code for the actual button:         */


/*   
        Spot is the span on the inside of the href that
        fills the parent and makes the hover and link work
        for the entire div
    */

.spot {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


/*
        This is the outer svg wrapper that the SVG itself will 
        fill. Multiple svg-wrapper classes can be put side by side.
    */

.svg-wrapper {
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  /*make sure to use same height/width as in the html*/
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px
}


/*
      This is where we define the fill, color, thickness,
      and stroke pattern of the SVG when there is no hover.
      The dasharray and offset together define the line position
      under the words. Here's also where the transition speed is set.
    */

#shape {
  stroke-width: 6px;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #FF00BD;
  stroke-dasharray: 85 400;
  stroke-dashoffset: -220;
  transition: 1s all ease;
}


/* 
        Pushing the text up into the SVG. Without this the
        text would be below the div's.
    */

#text {
  margin-top: -35px;
  text-align: center;
}

#text a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}


/* 
        Changing the shape on hover. I change the color of the stroke,
    make it thinner, then set it to again wrap around the entire parent element.
    */

.svg-wrapper:hover #shape {
  stroke-dasharray: 50 0;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke: #FF00BD;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav-area a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-area a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}


/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav-area.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav-area.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .nav-area.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.nav-area .icon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Joe's Portfolio</title>
</head>


<body>
  <!-- Navigation Bar -->
  <header class="fix">
  <div class="nav-area">
    <ul class="menu-area" id="mynav-area">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="work.html">Coursework</a></li>
          <li><a href="future.html">Future Aspirations</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
          <li><a href="cvpage.html.html">CV</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
      </ul>
      <!-- Navigation Bar End -->
```